# Cannot attach the MDF database without LDF log file

Tags: sql-server, database

I tried to attach MDF file and recreate database. FYI my log (LDF) was missing.

The error message generated by management studio is following

> The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure.

Kindly need help for this issue. Thank you!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186242/5203?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow? Is it MSSQL? In case of mssql: a) which version? b) have you tried sp_attach_db/sp_attach_single_file_db ?

Comment: It seems the source database wasn't cleanly detached using `sp_detach_db`. That should be done when the intent is to reattach.

Comment: hi Dan Guzman. You are correct, actually I copied the MDF file from the damaged server. I thought since the MDF is a physical file, I could re-attach at new server, as easy as that. So what do you think? No hope at all :'( oh God...

Comment: Hi Ingaz, thank you very much for your welcome :) yes my database is MSSQL. I finally find the solution! Anyway thank you :)

Comment: I finally find the solution, using this syntax "create database [DatabaseNameHere] on (filename = 'D:\DATA\DatabaseNameHere.mdf')
for ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG" the solution here is to use the ATTACH_FORCE_REBUILD_LOG. It works like a charm, eventhough I didn't properly detached the MDF due to server damage, it could re-create the log file. Using the Management Studio attach option and removing log file only works for proper detachment of MDF. For case whereby you haven't properly detach the MDF, use above solution. Hope this helps anyone who need it, I almost cried due to this problem :')